# Java JTable -- Highlight a certain entry when an external variable changes

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable such that:

```
ID #:          Name:
 0             Entry 0
 1             Entry 1
 2             Entry 2
```

When a variable:

```
private int HighlightEntryID = 2;
```

is set to an ID #, the JTable should then be able to highlight the corresponding entry.

I have created a Custom Cell Renderer and with the following code:

```
TableColumn column = CISTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
column.setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
```

I render cells based on the ID # column.  My questions are:

- It only highlights a specific (row, column) entry.  I want to highlight the whole row.  How do I highlight other columns in the same row?
- When the variable: HighlightEntryID is changed, the JTable doesn't automatically reflect the change.  I must refresh the table manually.  How do I refresh it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only highlights a specific (row, column) entry. I want to highlight the whole row. How do I highlight other columns in the same row?

I like to use [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for this.

> When the variable: HighlightEntryID is changed, the JTable doesn't automatically reflect the change. I must refresh the table manually. How do I refresh it automatically?

Invoke the following to force repainting of the entire table:

```
table.repaint();
```

Comment: When I use prepareRenderer() is seems to overwrite the selectionBackground color whenever an entry is selected (highlighted).  Is there a remedy to this?

Comment: The working examples provided with the link show you how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setDefaultCellRenderer(Object.class, new CustomCellRenderer()) method of JTable.. 
And also you should put highlightEntryID variable to your table class..